# Java Array in Jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I have a Java lib that I am pulling some data out of.

It out puts a 3D array. However I can not do anything with it.

```
[[D[]@5615a6e0
```

is the response I get. I have tried mapping it:

```
{ |arr| arr.map { |arr| arr.to_a } }
```

but i get nothing out, What is the best way to parse this java array for ruby use?

Comment: What is the signature of the Java method? If it returns a simple array you should be able to use it as-is. That looks like an array of arrays.

Comment: yes its a 3d array that gets returned

Comment: I'm confused what the issue is then; what are you trying to do with it, how are you actually using it, etc? AFAIK it should be an array of arrays (of arrays, if it's really a 3D array--the method signature I asked for really would be nice to know).

Comment: I want to out put into Rails to pass over via JSON. ANy sort of puts array comes back with [[[D rather than the data. Will a map work?

Comment: If you just `puts` an array you'll get the type signature--it's not going to magically format anything for you. If you want it as JSON, convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 9):

Should not be a problem.  Just use `to_a`

Java Code:

```
package com.test.sof;

public class MyTest {
    public static int[] ReturnTestArray() {
        int[] anArray = new int[3];
        anArray[0] = 1;
        anArray[1] = 2;
        anArray[2] = 3;
        return anArray;
    }
}
```

JRuby Code:

```
require 'java'
java_import com.test.sof.MyTest

java_array = MyTest.ReturnTestArray
p java_array
#=> int[1, 2, 3]@484c6b

ruby_array = Array.new
p ruby_array
#=> []
ruby_array = java_array.to_a

p ruby_array.size
#=> 3
p ruby_array.join(', ')
#=> "1, 2, 3"
```