# Java string array to ruby string

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

So, I've been delving into JRuby this week just for fun, and I'm working on using SWT to create some pretty stuffs.  Long story short, I grab a value from a `List` and it ends up as what I've deduced to be a Java String Array.  Like this:

```
java.lang.String[asdf]@52e50599
```

I need to be able to get this into a standard Ruby string, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to actually get the String (`asdf`) out of the string array using Java methods or JRuby methods.

**EDIT:**

Here is the snippet of code that grabs the string above

`list` is a `Swt::Widgets::List` JRuby object

`button` is a `Swt::Widgets::Button` JRuby object

```
button.add_selection_listener do
  name = list.get_selection
end
```

Name ends up as the `java.lang.String` object

**EDIT 2:**

I'm certain I'm looking for the inverse of this:

[JRuby Reference](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRuby-Reference#wiki-Arrays)

EDIT 3:

This question is a duplicate of: [Java Array in Jruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877934/java-array-in-jruby)

Comment: Please show the code in question. I don't have any idea whether you're even seeing this in Java or Ruby.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated accordingly